# PHP MYSQL increase value after 1 month dynamically

Tags: mysql

Hi guys I'm building a web application using PHP and MYSQL I'm using PDO
I want to increment one of my column in MYSQL after 1 month for example.
the maturity stars the value by one when the user registered on the site.

```
maturity default 1
after 1 month maturity = 2
after 2 months maturity = 3
after 3 months maturity = 4

if maturity == 12 it will stop increasing
```

and so on. up to 12 months and if this maturity reached 12 it will stop increasing automatically

I want to increment the value every month without pressing any button

Thank you guys. I tried creating the same logic by comparing date and time when the user registered on my application. Thanks

Comment: after a month starting from which date??  ... explains better ... updated your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: We need more context. _Increase dynamically_ means? Like a cron job or some kind of DB triggers.

Comment: hi i want to update without pressing any button automatically update i think like cron jo i read a lot of cron when I'm searching i think that's the best choice

Comment: Why do you need to store this? Just calculate it as and when you want to know it.

Comment: I think you need a cronjob to do this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should run a php cron job or something like that with a script

```
UPDATE user 
set maturity = maturity + 1
WHERE maturity < 13;
```